# SAS Code On Ranking Exam Performance Using Conditional Quantile Regression

Tags: r, sas, quantile, quantile-regression

I'm relatively new to R and coding in general and I have been trying to replicate an example provided in this [PDF](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/SAS0525-2017.pdf) (https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/SAS0525-2017.pdf) on quantile regressions in SAS. The example can be found on pages 14 to 17 and is applied on a simple data set to identify the performance percentiles of students when also controlling for their age.

I have never used SAS and tried to replicate the example in R using the quantreg package, but I have so far not been able to get the Regression Quantile Level results. (I don't care about the graphs)

Is there someone who can provide an example of the SAS code transalted into R?

EDIT: I'm sorry for posting this without an example as Mr. Cameron pointed out to me the format of my question wasn't adequate before. I hope this is more adequate now. Thank you for the help!

Here is an example of what I did:

```
library(faux)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(quantreg)
Student_ID <- c(LETTERS[1:26])
Age <- sample( x = 14:18, size = 26, replace = TRUE)
Exam_Data <- data.frame(Student_ID, Age)
Exam_Data$Score <- jitter(rnorm_pre(Exam_Data$Age, mu = 50, sd = 2, r = 0.8, empirical = TRUE))
Exam_Data_Rank <- Exam_Data %>%
mutate(Ranked_Standard = percent_rank(Score))
Score_rq90 <- rq(Score ~ Age  + I(Age^2), data = Exam_Data_Rank, tau = 0.9)

Score_rq90 <- rq(Score ~ Age + I(Age^2) +Student_ID, data = Exam_Data_Rank, tau = 0.9)
```

The last line of code produces an Error for me. My problem now is how I can use quantreq to get the score ranks of the individual student IDs. I can make a regression on the score itself, but I do not know how to regress in regards to each individual like they did in the example.

Comment: Hi Hermann. If you have a specific example of your own data and the code you have attempted so far, then perhaps someone here can show you where the problem is, but I'm afraid Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask people to translate or recreate code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main issue in your formula is that you're trying to add Student_ID to the formula. You might mean to use a fixed effect here, in which case you might need to construct FE variables yourself, or use either the `rqpd` or the `lqmm` packages to set up the data as a panel.

Turning to the document you referenced and using the data you supplied, this should reproduce what you're going for. This removes the Student_ID variable and replaces it with the Age variable cubed as well as the inverted age, and this works for different values of tau. I took the liberty of reproducing the graphs using from the example using the fitted data as well, just to make sure that everything was working properly:

```
library(faux)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(quantreg)
library(ggplot2)

Student_ID <- c(LETTERS[1:26])
Age <- sample( x = 14:18, size = 26, replace = TRUE)
Exam_Data <- data.frame(Student_ID, Age)
Exam_Data$Score <- jitter(rnorm_pre(Exam_Data$Age, mu = 50, sd = 2, r = 0.8, empirical = TRUE))
Exam_Data_Rank <- Exam_Data %>%
  mutate(Ranked_Standard = percent_rank(Score))

Score_rq90 <- rq(Score ~ Age  + I(Age^2), data = Exam_Data_Rank, tau = 0.9)

Score_rq_all <- rq(Score ~ Age + I(Age^2) + I(Age^3) + I(1/Age), data = Exam_Data_Rank, tau = c(seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1)))
fitted_data <- data.frame(x_vals = Score_rq_all$x, fitted_vals = Score_rq_all$fitted.values) %>%
  select(x_vals.Age, tidyselect::starts_with("fitted_vals")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = tidyselect::starts_with("fitted_vals")) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0("0", gsub(pattern = "fitted_vals", replacement = "",
                     x = name))) %>%
  rename("x_vals" = "x_vals.Age", "tau" = "name", "fitted_val" = "value")
  
first_graph <- ggplot(data = Exam_Data_Rank, aes(x = Age, y = Score)) +
  geom_point()

first_graph
 
second_graph <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = Exam_Data_Rank, aes(x = Age, y = Score)) +
  geom_smooth(data = fitted_data, aes(x = x_vals, y = fitted_val, group = tau, color = tau))
                 
second_graph
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Especially your comment about using FE variables has helped me a lot to understand the problem better and come up with a solution! I was really interested in how the individuals were re-evaluated when also considering their age! Thank you for the help!!!